# Oncreate call multiple times due to fragment transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

ffIn Main Activity,

```
private void navigateTo(int position) {
    Log.v(TAG, "List View Item: " + position);

    switch(position) {
    case 0:
            getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new Home(), Home.TAG).commit();
            break;
    case 1:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame,
                    TabbedActivity.newInstance(),
                    TabbedActivity.TAG).commit();
        break;
    case 2:
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, History.newInstance(), History.TAG).commit();
    }
}
```

When i navigate to my home fragment through navigation drawer(based on the method above), it run onCreate method everytime. From my understanding, fragment cycle should run oncreateview instead oncreate method when you navigate between the screen through navigation drawer(since onpause>oncreateview). Can anyone provide a solution for me that can make sure onCreate only run once?

Comment: onCreate is called only once during the lifecycle of the activity until it is destroyed. Fragment is attached to the activity. So i don't understand what you say

Comment: Sorry about the bad English explanation. My onCreate method in my home fragment is called everytime whenever my navigation drawer click on it. I don't want this to be happen, i pretty sure my activity(MainActivity) does not get destroyed.

Comment: Romero has answered your question `new Home()` also read frament lifecycle in the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new instances each time you call `navigateTo`.

You should do something like this...

```
FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

// try to find an existing instance
Fragment frag = fragManager.findFragmentByTag(Home.TAG);
if (frag == null) {
   // if none were found, create it
   frag = new Home();
}

fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, frag, Home.TAG).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it! With your code and I still need to add fragManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, frag, Home.TAG).addToBackStack(Home.TAG).commit(); in order to make it works!